# Run Docker in a GlusterFS cluster

Tags: docker, glusterfs

I have a GlusterFS cluster on three servers in replication and I would like to run Docker inside it, so it's available on all replicas.

The reason I want to achieve this is because I don't want to setup each server for every website.

Is it possible to make a Docker container available from all the servers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it possible to make a Docker container available from all the servers?

As in the non-running container file/s on the filesystem so it can be ran on multiple machines - then yes, as in running the same container on multiple machines - then yes, as in it somehow executing as one container across multiple machines - then no.

Comment: I'm very new to Docker and I don't understand very well. I want to run it on multiple machines and be able to update it from a single machine (e.g. change a file for one website).